# Changing an ImageView of one fragment makes an unwanted change to the layout of another fragment

Tags: android, layout, imageview, fragment

I have an activity that extends SherlockActivity and who inflates a view that contains 3 different fragments.

fragment1:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvTodayCal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:text="@string/tod_cal"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TitleBlackFont" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvTotalCalorNumb"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/tvRespBudget"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/tvRespBudget"
    android:text="@string/summ_3"
    android:textAppearance="@style/NumberGreenFont" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvRespBudget"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/btAddExer"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btAddExer"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
    android:text="@string/un_bud"
    android:textAppearance="@style/RedLittleFont" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btAddExer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/ivGlass01"
    android:text="@string/bt_add_exer" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btAddFood"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/btAddExer"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btAddExer"
    android:text="@string/bt_add_food" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivGlass08"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/ivGlass07"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:src="@drawable/vaso_vacio" />


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivGlass07"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/ivGlass06"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:src="@drawable/vaso_vacio" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivGlass06"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/ivGlass05"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:src="@drawable/vaso_vacio" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivGlass05"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/ivGlass04"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:src="@drawable/vaso_vacio" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivGlass04"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/ivGlass03"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:src="@drawable/vaso_vacio" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivGlass03"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/ivGlass02"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:src="@drawable/vaso_vacio" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivGlass02"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/ivGlass01"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:src="@drawable/vaso_vacio" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivGlass01"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:src="@drawable/vaso_vacio" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

fragment2:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Esto es health... "
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
```

and fragment3:

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/llTable"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_weight="0"
android:background="#66D1FABE"
android:padding="5dp" >

<View
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="#aaa" />

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:weightSum="4" >

    <View
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#aaa" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvBudgetTitle"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/budg_tit" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#aaa" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvFoodTitle"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/food_tit" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#aaa" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvExerciseTitle"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/exce_tit" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#aaa" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTotalTitle"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/total_tit" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#aaa" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:weightSum="4" >

    <View
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#aaa" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvBudgetQty"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="1178" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#aaa" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvFoodQty"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="620" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#aaa" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvExerciseQty"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="120" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#aaa" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTotalQty"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="1980" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#aaa" />
</TableRow>

<View
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="#aaa" />

</TableLayout>
```

I need to switch the ImageView dynamically when user select it, so in my main activity, I use:

```
iGlass2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivGlass02);
iGlass2.setOnClickListener(this);
iGlass2.setImageResource(R.drawable.vaso_lleno);
```

Everything its ok (I get the new image on the layout), but I lose the format of my fragment 3 (which by the way is a TableLayout with 2 rows and 4 columns).

I have do everything to try to fix it, but is impossible for me... can someone help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved it by changing the fragment3 from TableLayout to a combination of LinearLayouts to perform the same table.

Now my fragment3 looks:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/llTable"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#66D1FABE"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="5dp" >

<View
    android:id="@+id/upperBar1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="#aaa" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="4" >

    <View
        android:id="@+id/verticalUpBar1"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#aaa" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvBudgetTitle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/budg_tit" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvBudgetQty"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="1178" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/verticalUpBar2"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#aaa" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvFoodTitle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/food_tit" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvFoodQty"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="620" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/verticalUpBar3"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#aaa" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvExerciseTitle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/exce_tit" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvExerciseQty"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="120" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/verticalUpBar4"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#aaa" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvTotalTitle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/total_tit" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvTotalQty"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="1980" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/verticalUpBar5"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#aaa" />
</LinearLayout>

<View
    android:id="@+id/lowerBar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="#aaa" />

</LinearLayout>
```